# Can we use "Plusquamperfekt" with "Perfekt" as main clause instead of "Präteritum"?

Tags: tense, perfect-tense

In different books, it is stated that "Plusquamperfekt" has to be used with "Präteritum" but I didn't find whether there is a possibility to use it with "Perfekt" as both "Perfekt" and "Präteritum" refer to the same time point.

**EDIT**

In which tense the verbs must be conjugated when talking about more than two events all happened in the past and one after another?

Comment: Could you include a source? I'm interested in which book claims this to be the case.

Comment: I am saying the books didn't show examples with Perfekt but only Präteritum.

Comment: So do they only give Präteritum/Plusquamperfekt examples and no Perfekt/Plusquamperfekt ones, or do they actually state that you can only use the former combination, not the latter?

Comment: "Use with" is a bit blurry. What do you want to express?

Comment: @tofro I think it is clear as "Plusquamperfekt" can never be sued alone. However, I meant referring to two events both happened in the past but one after another.

Comment: That's what I thought. Answer below is based on that assumption

Comment: Examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

German is by far not as picky with the sequence of tenses as, for example, English:

Standard textbook examples:

> Weil ich am Morgen gut gefrühstückt hatte, war ich zum Mitagessen noch nicht hungrig.

(Subclause in *Plusquamperfekt*, main clause *Präteritum*)

> Weil ich am Morgen gut gefrühstückt hatte, bin ich zum Mitagessen noch nicht hungrig gewesen.

(main clause *Perfekt*, Subclause in *Plusquamperfekt*)

Also note *Präteritum* is not present in a lot of southern German dialects and Switzerland - That is why *Perfekt* is often used instead, even in *Hochdeutsch*.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at [DeReKo](https://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/korpora.html). Pluperfect in one clause and perfect in the other is entirely unremarkable.

> Nachdem sich Finanzminister Hans-Rudolf Merz lange gegen den Elterntarif gewehrt hatte, hat nun der Bundesrat dieses Modell als gleichwertige Alternative in die Vorlage aufgenommen. (St. Galler Tagblatt, 12.02.2009)

> Weil seine Frau ihm nicht rechtzeitig das Mittagessen serviert hatte, hat ein Mann in Melbourne das Haus der Familie angezündet. (Braunschweiger Zeitung, 28.07.2009)

> Nachdem der Lokführer ein Warnsignal abgegeben hatte, hat der Mann noch versucht, auf den Bahnsteig zurückzuklettern. (Nürnberger Zeitung, 02.09.2009)

> Weil er deutlich zu viel Alkohol getrunken hatte, hat ein Autofahrer in der Nacht zu Samstag auf gerader Strecke zwischen Höchstenbach und Wied die Kontrolle über sein Fahrzeug verloren. (Rhein-Zeitung, 09.02.2009)

> Wer den Erfolg bei einem heißen Abstiegskandidaten etwas souveräner erwartet hatte, hat für SG-Trainer André Schermuly die jüngsten Ergebnisse des Gegners übersehen. (Rhein-Zeitung, 31.03.2009)

> Was als humanitärer Einsatz begonnen hatte, hat sich längst zu einem Krieg ausgewachsen. (Hamburger Morgenpost, 29.12.2008)

> Nachdem das Gewerbeaufsichtsamt bereits nach der Auswertung von Stichproben Überschreitungen der Arbeitszeit von mehreren Stunden festgestellt hatte, hat das Krankenhaus eingelenkt. (Hannoversche Allgemeine, 14.05.2008)

This is not surprising insofar as there is a huge overlap between the preterite and perfect as far as usage is concerned (i.e. they are interchangeable in many contexts).